# PayPal DOnate Button: Hidden note

Tags: paypal

I have paypal donate button and I wanna send hidden note with it.
How can I add it?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to send a hidden note and from where?

Comment: I have donate button forum in user panel. SO basically I want to send user id inside that hidden note. And in paypal there is small icon ( https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-600-20091209-1/en_US/i/icon/icon_note_16x16.gif ) which shows user note when you hover on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal has documentation on [advanced donate buttons](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_donation_buttons#id08AAF0P0E9N).

Step 5. could be for you:

> Add advanced variables to the HTML
>   code of your payment button
>   (optional).
>
> If you are familiar with the HTML
>   programming and the advanced HTML
>   variables supported by Website
>   Payments Standard payment buttons, you
>   can enter them here. Select the
>   checkbox, and then enter the variables
>   in the text box that appears below it.
>
> Enter any advanced HTML variables in
>   the following, name/value-pair format:
>
> variableName=allowableValue

On a side note, connecting your Forum's user ID with the real name you get from a PayPal donation could be a privacy issue, even a legal problem in some jurisdictions. I'm quite sure it would be one here in Germany, even though the users who donate to you will probably not mind you knowing who they are.